# M-Delta disturbance of second order transfer function

Tags: matrices

In our robust control course, we learn about uncertainty in the model or in the parameters, so we try to model the worst case of parameter uncertainty on the planet.
Planet $G$ suffer from uncertainty in $z$, $p_1$, and $p_2$.
how to compute M-Delta representation for the system, I think it some times call it as LFT( Linear Fractional Transformation). Where $M$ represents the input and output and uncertainty,  and Delta is a diagonal matrix of $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$ as follow

$G(s)=(s+z)/(s+p_1)(s+p_2)$

where:

$p_1=a(1+m_1), \quad|m_1|<1$,

$p_2=b(1+m_2),\quad|m_2|<1$,

$z=c(1+m_3),\quad|m_3|<1$.

where $a, b, c$ are the nominal value of $p_1, p_2$ and $z$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you for making some changes. I have nominated your question to be reopen so that we can help you. All the best!